# Get max in fact table by dim parent and sub project IDs DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, aggregate-functions

I have a table with parent project IDs and sub project IDs. For each parent ID, I want to get the max revenue across all sub IDs and return the max value for the parent ID. The parent and sub project IDs are in my dimension table and my revenue is in my facts table. I've included an example table below of how it would work calculating the max revenue column by parent ID.

| Parent ID | Sub ID | Revenue | Max Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 201 | 25 | 100 |
| 1 | 301 | 50 | 100 |
| 2 | 102 | 75 | 75 |
| 2 | 202 | 50 | 75 |
| 2 | 302 | 45 | 75 |

I've tried creating a variable using the parent project ID in the dimension table, I've tried using MAXX() by ID's and that also didn't work. I tried implementing a bunch of methods online but those haven't worked either. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Try posting copiable data instead of a picture, and include your expected result.

Comment: How do I make it copiable? Thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post